# Generating integers from roman numbers

Tags: python

I want to create a function which gives the integer equivalent of a roman number.
I have the following dictionary.
roman_numbers={
"I":1,
"V":5,
"X":10,
"L":50,
"C":100,
"D":500,
"M":1000,
"IV":4,
"IX":9,"XL":40,"XC":90,"CD":400,"CM":900
}

Any ideas on how I can do it using the above dictionary which has special cases?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
roman = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000}

def roman_int(S):
    total= 0
    for i in S[::-1]:
        num = roman[i]
        if 3*num < total: 
            total -= num
        else: 
            total += num
    return total
```

Execution,

```
In [61]: roman_int("MCMXCIV")
Out[61]: 1994

In [62]: roman_int("IV")
Out[62]: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe:

```
roman_numbers={ "I":1, "V":5, "X":10, "L":50, "C":100, "D":500, "M":1000, "IV":4, "IX":9,"XL":40,"XC":90,"CD":400,"CM":900 }

def calc(x, di = roman_numbers):
    res, i = 0, 0
    while i < len(x):
        try:           
            res += di.get(x[i:i+2])
            i += 1
        except:
            res += di.get(x[i])
        i += 1
    return res

calc('MMCC')
```